# How to pass java varibales to html page code(inside a java string)?

Tags: java, html, string, formatting

I don't know how to explain the problem but I will try my best.

I have a html page code as below stored in sql database table

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   Dear ${RESOURCES.NAME},<br>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have to pull this code into a java string in my java app and then replace the content at places like `${RESOURCES.NAME}` with its actual value. The value is stored inside a java variable in my java app.

I am thinking of replaceing the ${variables} with %s and then use java string formatter to replace its content with my java variable but since there is so many such variable in my html page, so its tedious and i have to provide the arguments in string formatter in sequence also.

Can anybody suggest a better idea to do this?

Comment: There is something like an expression language: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html . Better start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the String.replace() method, for example :

```
String html = db.get(); // Your method to get the html field from the database
String name = "John Doe";
String output = html.replace("${RESOURCE.NAME}", name);
```

[Docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)